# Getting words separated by " / " with Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following fragment of code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="colors">
    <h1>Colors:</h1>
    
    <div class="recipe"></div>
</div>

<div class="numbers">
    <h1>Numbers:</h1>
    
    <div class="recipe"></div>
</div>

<div class="people">
    <h1>People:</h1>
    
    <div class="recipe"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var colors = 'yellow / black / purple',
    numbers = '5 / 15 / 25',
    people = 'Brad Pitt / Leonardo DiCaprio / Anne Hathaway';

$('.colors .recipe').html(colors.replace(/(\w+)\/*/g, '<em>$1</em><br>'));

$('.numbers .recipe').html(numbers.replace(/(\w+)\/*/g, '<em>$1</em><br>'));

$('.people .recipe').html(people.replace(/(\w+)\/*/g, '<em>$1</em><br>'));
```

*[Check out in jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/t5ReJ/)*

I am not good with regular expression, then I'm getting unexpected results on rendering separated values on their respective recipes (you can see more on jsFiddle posted above).

I mean, the following results are showing for me:

> [...]
>
> Brad
>
> Pitt
>
> / Leonardo
>
> DiCaprio
>
> [...]

And what I want and need is this:

> Brad Pitt
>
> Leonardo DiCaprio

No slashes, no separated names/surnames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need regex for this. The split method can do the job:

```
var colors = 'yellow / black / purple',
    numbers = '5 / 15 / 25',
    people = 'Brad Pitt / Leonardo DiCaprio / Anne Hathaway';

function wrapEm(e) {
    return "<em>" + e + "</em>";
}

people.split(" / ").join("<br/>");

$('.colors .recipe').html(colors.split(" / ").map(wrapEm).join("<br/>"));
$('.numbers .recipe').html(numbers.split(" / ").map(wrapEm).join("<br/>"));
$('.people .recipe').html(people.split(" / ").map(wrapEm).join("<br/>"));
```

**Split** like the name suggests, splits the string into an array by using the `/` as a delimiter.

Comment: You can still use regex with `.split()` if you need more leniency.  For example: `.split(/\s*\/\s*/)`.

Comment: Yes definitely don't go over-engineering. Totally slipped my mind when answering.

Comment: Where did the `em` tags go ?

Comment: And how about the `em`, @ibu?

Comment: Use `map()` to get the `em` tags: `colors.split("/").map(function(e) { return "<em>" + e + "</em>"; }).join("<br>");` Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FNT9g/

Comment: Edited answer to add that (hope you don't mind @ibu)

Comment: What does it means the `e` parameter of `wrapEm`?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge: `map()` takes a callback function with one arg and calls that function for each element in your array, so `e` here is the element that the function is being called for. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Replace your regex with this:

```
/([^\/]+)\/*/g
```

Instead of using `(\w+)` for words (which doesn't include spaces) you want `[^\/]+` meaning anything except a slash.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works perfect:

```
 $('.colors .recipe').html(colors.replace(/(\\)?\//g, '<em>$1</em><br>'));
```